# jquery get paragraphs in div

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have some html like this:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div>
        // another div
    </div>
    <p>First paragraph in outer div</p>
    <div>
        // another div
    </div>
    <a href="#">some anchor</a>
    <p>Second paragraph in outer div</p>
    <div>
        <p>Third paragraph in outer div</p> 
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        <p>First paragraph in inner div</p>
        <p>Second paragraph in inner div</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I get the parapraphs that are in the outer DIV but not the inner DIV?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`$('.outer').children('p')` or `$('.outer > p')`

See [Child Selector (“parent > child”)](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) and [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

---

If you have some paragraphs that are not direct children of outer div, you can use

```
$('.outer p').not('.inner p')
```

See [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the immediate children selector:

```
.outer > p {
    ...
}
```

As its name indicates, it gets all the `p` elements that are immediate children of all those elements whose class attribute is `outer`.

Using *jQuery* it would be `$('.outer > p')`.

**UPDATE:**

The only way I see through to get what you ask in your comment is:

```
.outer > p, .outer div:not(.inner) p {
    ...
}
```

What this does is to select the same elements as above, plus those `<p>` tags that are inside some `<div>` tag inside `.outer` that is not `.inner`. I don't think this is the best way to achieve what you want, but at least is a solution, hope that helps.

Comment: What if I have some paragraphs that are not direct children of my outer div (see edit to the post)